# How I adjust auto (height, width) of the iframe according to the devices like Tabs, Mobile devices etc

Tags: php, jquery

I am adding a facebook link in src(attr) of iframe and i want to show the fb page according to the device. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="fb_link" width="100%;" height="100%;" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have need to add javascript in your code. First you need to calculate the window width like this code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('.container iframe').css('width', width)
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks its working for mobile phones but not working for the tab because facebook plugin provides max width upto 500px . Any alternative for this?

Comment: As facebook page plugin documentation it provide width and height in the api url you can not override it and style also. please read the official documentation from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/